# ¿Cómo obtener los Children de un FlowLayoutPanel?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

¿Cómo obtener los `Children` de un `FlowLayoutPanel` de Windows Forms? Veo que no es igual que un `StackPanel` de WPF.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[FlowLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) no tiene esa propiedad, pero puedes usar en su lugar [Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
foreach (Control control in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls) { 
    //trabajar con el control        
}
```